# Combinations: choosing group by group and the Multiplication principle

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Consider the following questions. 20 People (12 Men, 8 Women) are in a group. A committee of 10 people is to be selected. Find how many ways to select people for the below two different situations.

1. If the committee will consist of 8 members and 2 co-chairs.
2. If the committee will consist of at least 2 women.

For (Q1), the thinking of the answer is;

(Choose 8 members from 20) * (choose 2 co-chairs from the **remaining 12 people**)

Is this an application of the Multiplication principle? Anyway, my emphasis is on the second part of the selection where **we choose from 12 people who are remaining after the 1st selection**. I have seen this method used in textbooks, however, I have not come across a text that goes into details of this method and explains when this thinking cannot be applied.

For (Q2), I wanted to apply the **same thinking as in Q1**. That is;
(Choose 2 from 8 women) * (choose any **8 from the remaining 18 people**).
I have found out that, this thinking does not produce the correct answer. i.e. the Multiplication principle cannot be applied. The reason why we cannot apply this thinking is that, this produces combinations such as [ (W1 W2 ) + (W3 + 7 men)] and [(W1 W3) + (W2 + same 7 men)] which are the same (because the final group has no differentiation such as co-chairs and non-co-chairs. Everyone is a group member without differentiation, so a person coming to the final group via the 1st selection vs via the 2nd selection does not make a difference)

Therefore, in order to detect that this problem can arise or not, I have made up following tests

1. When Choosing **From different groups**: If we choose members from two different groups, then the multiplication principle applies i.e. (choose for sub group 1) * (choose for sub group 2).

Eg. Choose a committee of 4 men and 6 women from the above group.
We can choose 4 men from 12 men, and 6 women from 8 women. And multiply.

The same person cannot come into the final group via both selections because we choose from different groups.

2. When Placing **To different sub groups**: If we place selected items to different sub groups (eg. Co-chair and members), then the multiplication principle applies i.e. (choose for sub group 1) * (choose for sub group 2)

Eg. (Q1) above.
The same person can indeed come into the final group via both selections, however, the person will be in different sub groups of the final group, depending on whether the person came via the 1st or 2nd selection (eg. co-chair vs member)

3. **When Choosing From the same group, and Placing To one group**: If we choose members from the same group and place them into one group without differentiation, then the multiplication principle **DOES** **NOT** apply. For this type of sums, we have to enumerate the sub group break downs and calculate combinations individually. That is (2W + 8M), (3W+7M), (4W+6M)…etc. Or, we can take a shortcut by subtracting (10M) + (1W+9M) from 20C10

Q2 above is an example for this.

What am I expecting?

1. I would be thrilled to read a textbook/web page that explains this problem and possible solutions
2. Are my 3 rules correct? Is there a better way to detect when to apply the Multiplication principle?

Comment: You are correct that you can apply the multiplication principle when selecting from *disjoint* sets.  The reason your first approach to the second question did not work is that the two sets of people (the two women and the additional people) are not disjoint.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, Even if we choose people from non-disjoint sets, if we place them to dis-joint sets in the final group, then the multiplication principle applies?

Anyway, have you come across a textbook or a website that explains this further?

Comment: Per the comment of @N.F.Taussig, Let $A$ denote the answer to question 1, $B$ denote the answer to question 1, with the constraint that **no** women are on the committee, and $C$ denote the answer to question 1, with the constraint that **exactly** one woman is on the committee.  The standard approach to question 2 is to compute $B$ and $C$.  Then, the final answer to question 2 is $A - (B + C).$

Comment: Per my previous comment, I am assuming that the question 1 constraints of 8 people on the committee, with 2 co-chairs, also applies to question 2.

Comment: @user2661923, Q1 and Q2 are not interrelated.

Comment: Then, for Q2, how many people will be on the committee, and will there be any co-chairs?

Comment: @user2661923, The committee will have 10 people. There are no co-chairs and non-co-chairs. All 10 are just members, however, at least 2 women have to be selected to the committee

Comment: Then, the standard approach is to compute $A = $ the number of ways of selecting any $10$ people, $B = $ the number of ways of selecting any $10$ people where none of them are women, and $C = $ the number of ways of selecting any $10$ people where exactly one of them is a  woman. Then, the answer to question 2 will be $A - (B + C).$